# Centrado de items en dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Estoy construyendo una pagina usando clases de bootstrap, sin embargo hay cosas que no me gustan e intento cambiarlas, el texto del tag a aparece en la parte de arriba a la izquierda, cuando debería aparecer centrado pero a la izquierda e igual los márgenes del desplegable muestra unos márgenes vacíos que no se pueden quitar.

En la siguiente imagen, se puede ver que el hover no cubre ni la parte inferior ni la parte superior completamente y se muestra un margen vacío, además que el texto no esta centrado verticalmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="../assets/img/pgsico.png"/></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Accesorios Y Periféricos 
                        <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                    </a>&nbsp;
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Mouse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Teclados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Diademas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Cámaras Web</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">MousePads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Kits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Bases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Reguladores</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Componentes 
                        <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                    </a>&nbsp;
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Procesadores </a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Tarjetas de Video</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Tarjetas Madre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Memorias Ram</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Unidades SSD</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Unidades HDD Internos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Gabinetes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Fuentes De Poder</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Iluminación</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Enf. Líquido (AIO)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Enf. Aire</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Ventilación</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Sillas Gamer
                        <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                    </a>&nbsp;
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Cooler Master</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Game Factor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">Yeyian</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item">XZeal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                </li>
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Y aquí está el css de ello, ya intenté con `display: inline-block;` entre otras cosas:

```
ul li ul {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    ul li ul li a {
        border-radius: 0;
        min-height: 45px;
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: 250px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    li a {
        border-radius: .3rem;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: var(--button-border-hover);
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Originalmente está de esta manera solamente quiero conservar las líneas mas oscuras divisoras y que se muestre centrado y cuadrado.

Así es el original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor añade un ejemplo [mínimo, verificable y reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ya lo logré, es la clase de bootstrap que tiene un estilo que le da margen superior e inferior y crea esos espacios, se sobreescribe el bootstrap-menu con el estilo que se quiera dar y se arregla